# Set var value after finding the variable by a name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm starting to build a script and so far it has 3 properties. `var url, top, left;`

I want to loop through the properties that the user has entered and set the values in the correct `var's`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.initEmail({
        url: "localhost:54623",
        left: "10",
        top: "15"
    });
});



$.fn.initEmail = function (options) {
    var url, top, left;
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.initEmail.Options, options);

    $.each(opts, function (n, x) {
        //If n match one of the variables, then set the value.
    });
}
```

Is this possible in some way or is there a much easier way.?

Comment: Not really. I wouldn't bother with the loop though.
`url = opts.url; // etc`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fn.initEmail({
        url: "localhost:54623",
        left: "10",
        top: "15"
    });
});



$.fn.initEmail = function (options) {
    var url = options.url, top = options.top, left = options.left;
    var opts = $.extend({}, $.fn.initEmail.Options, options);

}
```